# data factory flatten to show sub arrays

Tags: azure-data-factory

### Question, how do I get the values for the location in preview?
For the below json

```
},
        "parcels": [
            {
                "name": "kljkl",
                "state": "fgfgf",
        ...
                "quantities": [
                    {
                        "planned": "ertert",
                        "uom": "trert"
                    },
                    {
                        "actual": "fdgdfg",
                        "uom": "hhh"
                    }
                ],
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "name": "sfdsdfsdf",
                        "code": "cbcvb",
                        "type": "Refinery"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "jhjhjhj",
                        "code": "tryfghgh",
                        "type": "bnmbn"
                    }
                ],
        ...
            },
            {
...
```

---

I have a flatten activity
unroll by --> [] parcels

unroll root --> [] parcels

In preview I can see
1- parcel columns --> name and state populated.

Then I added another flatten activity to see the values of location[]

[image]

But I get an error:

![error message][3]

![enter image description here][3]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY46F.png)

Comment: Any thoughts for the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Error message states, you cannot add the mapping of the array which is already unrolled/flattened.

As you have already flattened parcels array in your previous transformation, you cannot select the array which already unrolled under mappings.

[image]

Add mappings of the columns under parcels array as shown below.

[image]

Data preview:

[image]

Comment: This is what I have now (using braching for each array under parcels, i.e. one flatten for location, one for quantity, etc.) for each of the arrays, i.e. location, quantities. Question: How do I put them together so that I can get the field from each flatten activity into one? thanks